# Best way to run Whatsapp on a 32 bit Ubuntu in 2018 without having a smartphone?

Tags: 14.04, whatsapp

I know there are multiple answers on this topic, but most of them are outdated (2015 or older), and suggest the use of either Genymotion or AndY, both not anymore being available for 32 bit Systems. 
My own try was installing Oracle Virtual Box, and installing the latest x86-Android (android-x86-8.1-rc1.iso). It is stuck in the boot process, and I can only see the logo.
I can't belive that I'm supposed to buy a new lap top to use software that essentially does not do mutch more than sending text messages.

My system is Ubuntu 14.04, I have 2 GB RAM and an Intel Dualcore CPU with 1.3 GHz frequency (Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     U7700). I don't own a smartphone.

Edit: This question is about 2018, not about 2015, and it's not about Whatsapp webapp (since as I've written, I don't own a smartphone). I'm asked to make an edit do clarify why this question is not a duplicate, this is it.

Comment: You might want to try https://web.whatsapp.com/. I don't think the app itself is available for Ubuntu. Not much we can do about it.

Comment: You didn't really read my question, did you?

Comment: I don't think there is any way to use WA on Ubuntu within the limits outlined. :~)

Comment: Ok, that answers my question :) (although it's sad to hear that a technology you're kind of forced into requires you to buy new hardware (especially smartphone), while old one would in principle still capable of doing the job.)